# How to display divs one at a time when clicking a link

Tags: jquery, html, hidden

Take a look [here](http://space.equiet.sk/)

Every div is hidden and when clicking one button from the menu it shows the specific content (div) and others are hidden. Only the home page and the selected content are shown. My question is... how do you do this using jquery? how do you hide every content except  the fist div and when clicking the menu the selected content appears?

Example:

my menu looks like this:

```
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="#home" class="active">Home</li>
    <li><a href="#page1">Page 1</li>
    <li><a href="#page2">Page 2</li>
    <li><a href="#page3">Page 3</li>
</ul>
</nav>

<article id="page1">
<div class="container">
    <h1>Page 1</h1>
        <p>Page 1 content</p>
</div>
</article>


 <article id="page2" class="dark">
<div class="container">
    <h1>Page 2</h1>
    <p>Page 2 content</p>
</div>
</article>


  <article id="page3">
<div class="container">
    <h1>Page 3</h1>
    <p>Page 3 content</p>
</div>
 </article>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can change anchor `href` values same as the target element's `id`:

```
<li><a href="#home" class="active">Home</li>
<li><a href="#page1">Page 1</li>
<li><a href="#page2">Page 2</li>
<li><a href="#page3">Page 3</li>
```

```
$('a:not(:first)').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  var href = $(this).attr('href')
  $('article').hide();
  $(href).show()
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NAbVs/1/)

Comment: ooh ok. then what function do I have to do for the menu? (li) to display the selected content and hide the previous shown content?

Comment: Do you know `why` my answers' upvotes are not added to my reputation? `:)`

Comment: Not so long ago I experienced the same issue about missing upvotes :) And wrote to support - apparently you can earn only **200** reputation on a single day (accepts, bounties don't count) - [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

Comment: @ZoltanToth thanks for the link, i had read that question, i have earned `305` reputation in a day do far but I don't why this occurs sometimes, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The snippet you provided is a little confusing, but perhaps you're looking for [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)?

Comment: I try to avoid `toggle` because it can get weird with multiple elements.

Comment: Sorry dsp_099 im using html 5 coding... I agree with Andrew.

Comment: Yeah I answered before he posted the URL so I wasn't exactly sure what he was asking. True enough.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to hide what you don't need initially.

```
.container { display:none; }
```

Then you can put the `href` and `id` attributes to good use, as follows

```
$('.link').click(function(){
  var correspondingDivId = $(this).attr('href'); //get id of div to be shown

  $('.container').hide(); //hide all the containers

  $(correspondingDivId).show(); //show only the one we need

});
```

You would obviously need to change your markup a little bit.

```
<a href='#Div1'>Link 1 </a>
.
.
<div id="Div1" class="container"   />
```

Comment: yes I'll have to display:none but how do you do the jquery part?

Comment: "href" is an `.attr`, not a `.prop`.

Comment: @Blazemonger: Corrected my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about JQuery (why do so many rely on a framework?), but this is easily achieved using the style.display attribute.  Set to 'block' or 'none'to show / hide.

Answer (score 0):

In pure CSS you could do `article { display:none; }` `article:first-child { display:block; }`. This will show the first `article` while hiding the rest.

Comment: @RickyCortes You asked how to hide everything but the first... That's how. If you want to display, give the links an `href` property that corresponds to the `div` you want to show and then manage show/hide with that.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use the `hashchange` event (even though IE7 doesn't support it) -- this approach makes individual articles bookmarkable:

```
$(window).on('hashchange',function() {
    var hash = location.hash;
    $('article').hide();
    $(hash).show();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).trigger('hashchange');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Look at the documentation: [http://api.jquery.com/visual/](http://api.jquery.com/visual/#?q=) (Effects -> Basiscs -> `show(speed, callback)`) study a little, and certainly you will be able to do alone.

Comment: I need help from someone... if you're not willing to, just ignore my question and go back to what you were doing -_____-